# Font being rendered: System Default

Tags: html, css, dom, rendering, font-face

I've applied Open Sans Font to most of a site I am working on. Specifically to the labels. However I am facing a conundrum here. The site is live and rendering the font as it should, but the section I am working on locally (which uses the exact same files as the one live and the code implemented is the same as well) does not render the Open Sans font in the labels. Instead, the System Default font is being rendered which I believe is Helvetica. The interesting thing here is that Helvetica is not even the System Default (browser)! It's the Bootstrap Default font. So, someone is lying.

Here is a screenshot of an Xray of my label font

[image]

And here is a screenshot of my Firebug telling me Open Sans is the active font, and Helvetica (inactive) coming from bootstrap.min.css. Yet, this is the one being rendered.

[image]

I'd add code to a JFiddler is you need me to, but I don't think it would be of too much help. But ask, and you shall receive :)

Is there a technique I am not using or I should use? It works in the live version, so I know the code has to work.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Check the source when on the local server, inside the <link> tag is the localserver domain overwriting the actual domain of the font? I've had that happen before.

Comment: That's the first thing I checked. The sources look identical.